# How did /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list get installed on my rpi systems?

Tags: raspbian

This source is a microsoft repository. Surely this shouldn't be installed by default!  It seems to have been installed in an upgrade a few days ago.

Comment: It's part of the changes to RaspiOS to support their new Raspberry Pi Pico with Microsoft's wonderful VSCode development tool. If you're not going to use VSCode then either ignore it or edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list to comment out the new repo or delete /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list. Your choice, pick your poison.

Answer (score 3):

That was in an update of raspberrypi-sys-mods

See RPF forum for more info / discussion: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=301011&hilit=vscode#p1807288

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget the GPG key from them in the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ directory if my memory serves me.

Comment: I presume you meant to write "Don't forget to delete the GPG key ... ".  Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it was in reference to getting rid of MS on your computer, the last part of it, is no gpg key left over. I have solved the problem myself with a nice fresh install of Debian buster on my Pi 4 works great, at least I get change logs that explain what goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Wow and Steve Ballmer the former CEO of MS called linux a "Cancer that needed to be removed", my my how times have changed.