# Could not connect to packages.microsoft.com

Tags: raspbian

Since few days I got always the same error when I run `apt update`:

```
Could not connect to packages.microsoft.com:80
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Why do my linux box (*raspbian*) try to connect to a microsoft server!?!

**What is that new repository and how it landed in my operating system?**

I'm really surprised ...do I missed something?

Thank in advance for your lights

Comment: Its for Visual Studio Code it you decide to install it.

Comment: ok, thanks... but I didn't "decide" anything.
I even don't use Visual Studio so why do I got these errors

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120868/how-did-etc-apt-sources-list-d-vscode-list-get-installed-on-my-rpi-systems

Comment: If you have a PiHole, it might be blacklisted ...

Comment: Yes indeed, that answers the question but it raises a thousand others that will not be discussed here. Thank you for your answers